# Google Cloud alert policy not triggering through Firebase's SDK invocations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I've set up an alert policy in my GCP Project to fire an alert every time an object is inserted in an specific bucket. I did this using the `request_count` metric with the `WriteObject` label.

This alert policy works fine when I add files to the bucket in the GCP console or through the REST APIs.

In my Android and iOS applications I use the Firebase SDK to interact with this bucket storage. Everything works fine, the files are added to the bucket, but my alert policy is not triggering. Does the Firebase SDK call the same GCP APIs? Is there something wrong with my `filter` in the alert policy?

I'll insert the Alert Policy Code below as it may help to solve the issue:

```json
{
  "displayName": "File uploaded alert policy",
  "userLabels": {},
  "conditions": [
    {
      "displayName": "File uploaded",
      "conditionThreshold": {
        "filter": "resource.type = \"gcs_bucket\" AND resource.labels.bucket_name = \"bucket-x\" AND metric.type = \"storage.googleapis.com/api/request_count\" AND metric.labels.method = \"WriteObject\"",
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "900s",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_NONE",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_COUNT"
          }
        ],
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
        "duration": "0s",
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "alertStrategy": {
    "autoClose": "3600s"
  },
  "combiner": "OR",
  "enabled": true,
  "notificationChannels": [
    "projects/channel-x",
    "projects/channel-y"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or how could I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** Including the information that Doug asked for in his comment.

I'm using the Firebase SDK to upload files to the bucket. In the Android application, for instance, the relevant package is `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0`. After including the dependency, the following snippet uploads the file to the bucket.

```kotlin
fun firebaseUpload(filename: String, fileUri: Uri) {
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("<BUCKET_URL>")
    val uploadTask = storage.getReference("/${filename}.zip").putFile(fileUri)

    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener { ... }
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener { ... }
}
```

It might be important to say that the `filename` variable includes a timestamp to avoid overriding files in the bucket.

Comment: For completeness, you should show the code that uploads to the bucket.  We should be able to take your instructions to reproduce the issue exactly as you've described.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the question trying to include the information you asked for. It's not much as almost everything is handled by the Firebase's SDK library.